# Is Javascript code generated by PHP bad practise?

Tags: php, javascript, code-generation

i am wondering this question as i was thinking of either creating javascript code normally in a seperate js file or making it generated via PHP, can someone tell me if it is bad practice if it is generated via PHP?

Comment: If you need your JavaScript to be generated dynamically, then why not do it? If you pay attention to security concerns, it should not be a problem.

Comment: What's the benefit? Seems like it would be harder to maintain if you generated it within PHP.

Comment: At least 99% of the time you don't actually need to do it, and a "normal" solution via "static" javascript is available.

Comment: Can you revise the question to give a specific example of when you would need to do this?

Comment: Similar, more popular question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it isn't necessarily bad practice, you should try to avoid it at all costs, primarily in the name of long term code maintainability. If you don't need to be dynamically generating JavaScript, you shouldn't.

Even still, when it does need to be generated dynamically, most of the time you are just generating dynamic variables.

It would be a wise decision to write a static javascript file and then dynamically generate a script tag with variables.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var message = "<?= $my_message ?>";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="static-message.js" />
```

Where static-message.js contains:

```
  alert("Your message: " + message);
```

This works because message variable gets set prior to the loading of the static-message.js file.

Answer (score 2):

It's about as bad as practice as generating HTML, so no - it's fine to do so.
However, if your JavaScript never changes, a separate file for it would be ideal.

Comment: It's similar, but I think it's not quantitatively the same: 1) HTML is much simpler than JS; 2) HTML, especially the dynamic part you'd generate, is a bit like data, not just code (and generating data is okay); 3) Even for HTML, for more complex documents, a structured approach like templates is desirable, to only generate a limited part.

Answer (score 1):

I'd not if I could help it. Unless there's no other way to handle it. Maintainability and test-ability come to mind. And it's a fairly language-agnostic question. You might get away with it in a purely interpreted language, but if you do something like that in a compiled/semi-compiled language, you could be in pain. I'd vote for minimizing the mixing of the to. If you have to expose a data element for JS to work on do just than and keep the rest of the JS in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

I often generate CSS files dynamically using PHP. This allows you to create a CSS style sheet that can be shared across multiple projects, but also contain customized styles that related specifically to a project.

The same can be applied to other resources. Including JavaScript, images, PDF documents, etc.. etc..

The key to a successfully doing this with PHP is applying the correct header information. Including how the browser should cache the response. You might also want to cache the output from the script to a temp file. To make future requests for the same information quicker to load.

Answer (score 0):

It's very convenient to be able to do so, but I wouldnt recommend doing so purely from a code maintenance and code clarity point of view. Also some editors dont have good intellisense for JS code that has server content too.